# The difference between HO strings and HE strings

Tags: string-theory, duality

I've understood that both string theories involve a hybrid of superstrings and bosonic strings. But i can't find the difference between these two theories. Can anyone explain the difference?

Comment: See e,g.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterotic_string_theory).

Comment: @Qmechanic i have, i still dont see the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gauge groups of these theories are different -- $SO(32)$ for HO string, and $E_8 \times E_8$ for HE string. This difference is a consequence of different geometry of internal $T^{16}$ on which one of the sectors in each of these theories is compactified (if you prefer such a geometrical picture). Being compactified on tori, these theories are equivalent to each other via T-duality, and have $SO$ gauge groups.